# RxSwift computed Variable combined from 2 other Variables

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I need to have `var isOn: Variable<Bool>` that is computed from 2 other Variables. How can I subscribe to value changes of the other Variables while being able to read latest value from my `isOn` Variable as well?

Below is the bad solution using 2 variables of type `Observable` and `Variable`. But I am looking for the correct solution, basically to merge my `isOn` and `isOnVariable` into single one.

```
let from = Variable<Date?>(nil)
let to = Variable<Date?>(nil)

let isOnVariable = Variable<Bool>(false)
var isOn: Observable<Bool> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(from.asObservable(), to.asObservable()) { [weak self] to, from in
        switch (from, to) {
        case (.none, .none):
            self?.isOnVariable.value = false
            return false
        default:
            self?.isOnVariable.value = true
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let from = Variable<Date?>(nil)
let to = Variable<Date?>(nil)
let isOnVariable = Variable<Bool>(false)
Observable.merge(from.asObservable(), to.asObservable())
            .map { [weak self] (_) -> Void in
                guard let `self` = self else {
                    return
                }
                switch (self.from.value, self.to.value) {
                case (.none, .none):
                    self.isOnVariable.value = false
                default:
                    self.isOnVariable.value = true
                }
            }
            .subscribe()
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Now you can subscribe to isOnVariable an listen for value changes, and in any moment you can access values from the `from` and `to` variable. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, so you can just change logics in the `.map` but you got the idea.
If you are interested in why I'm using `weak self` this is a good reading http://adamborek.com/memory-managment-rxswift/

Comment: Thanks very much! I've discovered another option which follows the same principle, just slightly more concise code, see my answer below.

Comment: isn't this should be done in do() bc you are making some side effects by calling self.isOnVariable.value ?

Answer (score 2):

While working with @markoaras's answer, there is another option to use `combineLatest` and bind it to `isOn` `Variable`. It follows the same principle.

```
let isFromOpen = Variable<Bool>(false)
let isToOpen = Variable<Bool>(false)
let isOn = Variable<Bool>(false)
Observable.combineLatest(from.asObservable(), to.asObservable()).map{ (from, to) -> Bool in
            return from != nil || to != nil
        }.bind(to: isOn).disposed(by: bag)
```